# Google Sheets - Inventory: Auto-pick from different BINs for same items?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible through Google Sheets to have items based on order entry deduct from multiple bins? I have a list of products, and there are several entries for the same item in different bins/containers/pallets, and if an order comes in, I want it to be able to deduct from the first bin until 0, then move onto the next sequentially until the order is fulfilled. The output would give the bin# that it was picked from, and the quantity.

Here is an example scenario and the orders. The order list would be what will generate based on the Orders sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15yldGJEuRpyiLLA1YHfE6HV0yjDlv89olQXilh52gz8/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you geniuses in advance!

I've tried various different types of methods to try to attempt it but it just fails every time. The closest I got was to deduct the first BIN completely if the order quantity exceeds the bin count, but I couldn't get it to move on to the next bin to continue picking the rest of the quantities.